# Electron affinity of isotopes anomaly

Tags: isotope, electron-affinity

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity_(data_page)) the electron affinity of $\ce{^{2}H}$ is higher than the electron affinity of $\ce{^{1}H}$ however the electron affinity of $\ce{^{18}O}$ is lower than $\ce{^{16}O}$. How is this anomaly explained?

Comment: I'll be impressed if someone has a qualitative but accurate explanation for an effect measured at the sixth decimal place.

Comment: Yet it is still a anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

Heavier nuclei have less spatial spread than light nuclei (in chemistry, we often ignore that because electrons have many times more). For these elements, that have the extra electron constrained in its orbital to add more repulsion to the outer shell, such as oxygen and fluorine, more spread in the position of their nucleus helps to lessen that repulsion. For these elements, that have less constrained outer shell (hydrogen and sulfur in Wikipedia's table), the  stabilization of extra electron at heavier nucleus comes from the reduced mean distance from the common center of mass of the nucleus and the electron.

That said, it is not obvious from looking at the mentioned table only. To know, which elements have more "pressure" in their electron shells, we need to also know a lot about ionic radii, for example.